# cakephp console issue : not able to set path

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to create a controller in cakephp(1.3) using console. I am using windows XP and XAMPP.

My current cake console settings below

C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\console>cake

> ♀ Welcome to CakePHP v1.3.4 Console
>   --------------------------------------------------------------- Current Paths:  -app: console 
>   -working: C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\console
>   -root: C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake 
>   -core: C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog
>
> Changing Paths: your working path
>   should be the same as your application
>   path to change your path use the
>   '-app' param. Example: -app
>   relative/path/to/myapp or -app
>   /absolute/path/to/myapp
>
> Available Shells:  acl [CORE]
>   i18n [CORE]
>
> api [CORE]
>   schema [CORE]
>
> bake [CORE]
>   testsuite [CORE]
>
> console [CORE]
>
> To run a command, type 'cake
>   shell_name [args]' To get help on a
>   specific command, type 'cake
>   shell_name help'
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\console>-app
>   c:\xampp '-app' is not recognized as
>   an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\console>

what are the path settings I need to set for creating a controller from console ?
I tried to change the app path but, when I type command **cake**  It goes app directory to console,

Answer (score 1):

`-app` is a *parameter* for the `cake` command:

```
C:\...\console>cake -app C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\app
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also run cake console without problems, provided you're at the correct path. Try the following:

`C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\>C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\console\cake`

or, to save yourself the trouble, add `C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\apressblog\cake\console` to the %PATH% environmental variable.